# Applying jQuery autocomplete json datasource on a dynamically driven form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, autocomplete

New to jQuery and Javascript and am not sure on how to replace this autocomplete

```
// autocomplete enablement
    var availableAttributes = [
      "account_address",
      "account_address_city",
      "account_address_country",
      "account_address_state",
      "account_address_street1",
      "account_address_street2",
      "account_address_zip",
      "account_email",
      "account_login",
      "account_name",
      "account_number",
      "account_telephone"
    ];
```

in

```
  $(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
// autocomplete enablement
    var availableAttributes = [
      "account_address",
      "account_address_city",
      "account_address_country",
      "account_address_state",
      "account_address_street1",
      "account_address_street2",
      "account_address_zip",
      "account_email",
      "account_login",
      "account_name",
      "account_number",
      "account_telephone"
    ];
    $( "input[name^='mytext']" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableAttributes
    });     

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append($('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>').find(":text").autocomplete({
        source: availableAttributes
    })); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })


  });
```

with (the jQuery Jason Remote Datasource Autocomplete. Link http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp)

```
  $(function() {
    function log( message ) {
      $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
      $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }

    $( "#city" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          data: {
            q: request.term
          },
          success: function( data ) {
            response( data );
          }
        });
      },
      minLength: 3,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        log( ui.item ?
          "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
          "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
      },
      open: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
      },
      close: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
      }
    });
  });
```

Complete HTML, ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5n22tot7/))

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
var availableAttributes = [ "account_address", "account_address_city", "account_address_country", "account_address_state", "account_address_street1", "account_address_street2", "account_address_zip", "account_email", "account_login", "account_name", "account_number", "account_telephone"];

$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            // $(wrapper).append('<div><input id="' + x + '" type="text" name="mytext"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
            $(wrapper).append('<div>' + '<input id="' + x + '" type="text" name="mytext"><br>' + '<textarea name="desc[]"></textarea>' + '<a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a>' +'</div>');
            $("input[id=" + x + "]").autocomplete({
                source: availableAttributes
            });
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    })
});

// autocomplete enablement
$(function() {
    $("input[name^='mytext']").autocomplete({
        source: availableAttributes
    });
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="input_fields_wrap">
        <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
        <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
        <textarea name="desc[]"></textarea>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What webservice are you planning on using?

Comment: @BG101, html css javascript, jQuery, php, mysql

Comment: the url I meant sorry.

Comment: @url?, am not sure what you are asking. I was planning to apply jQuery autocomplete via JSON data source to the above dynamically driven form. You have a working example here [link] (http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp)

Comment: the `jsonp` has to come from somethere. in that example it is *http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity*

Comment: @BG101, yes true. The url to be used will be that of my app folder but right now I was trying to incorporate this jQuery json autocomplete into the above form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example of what you posted

```js
$(document).ready(function() {    
   
$(".myText").autocomplete({

source: function (request, response) {
 jQuery.getJSON(
 "http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity?callback=?&q="+request.term,
 function (data) {
  response(data);
 }
 );
},
minLength: 3
 });

var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

var x = 1; //initlal text box count
$(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
        // $(wrapper).append('<div><input id="' + x + '" type="text" name="mytext"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        $(wrapper).append('<div>' + '<input id="' + x + '" type="text" class="myText" id="myText"><br>' + '<textarea name="desc[]"></textarea>' + '<a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a>' +'</div>');
        
        $("#" + x).autocomplete({

source: function (request, response) {
 jQuery.getJSON(
 "http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity?callback=?&q="+request.term,
 function (data) {
  response(data);
 }
 );
},
minLength: 3
 });
    }
});

$(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
});
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
        <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
        <div><input type="text" class="myText" name="myText" id="myText"></div>
        <textarea name="desc[]"></textarea>
    </div>
```

Comment: need to replace the above auto complete with http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

Comment: I have updated it, you will need to write your own page to return the json if you want to load it using the remote option. But this one works with the jquery example

Comment: you are very close. Yes it works but only for the first field. Once you click the button "Add More Fields" then the autocomplete stops working on the second field. Can you please rectify it before I accept your answer.